# Dynamic Watermark php Script gives "the image cannot be displayed because it contains errors"

Tags: php, dynamic, watermark

I'm try to use http://www.htmlguard.com/articles/dynamic-image-watermarks-with-php/ script in my localhost. It gives "the image cannot be displayed because it contains errors" message while I run it. I didn't change anything in script. I'm using wamp for run php scripts.

Do you have an idea why this is happen?

Thanks

Comment: probably a php error/warning is being output before the image data, causing it to no longer look like a jpg/png/whatever. Enter the script's url directly into the address bar of the browser, safe the resulting file (even if it says "cannot be displayed"). then look at that file in a text/hex editor for anything obviously NOT image data.

Comment: I enter directly "http://localhost/testsite/watermark.php?image=http://localhost/testsite/photo/example1.jpg&watermark=images/watermark.png" but I get error message

Comment: and this error message is... what? can't help you if you don't accurately describe the problem.

Comment: I put script link to top of page, I didn't change anything and I try that in my localhost. What else should I say?

Comment: the script's source is irrelevant. what matters is if your server is capable of running it. what error message are you getting?

Comment: the image "http://localhost/testsite/watermark.php?image=http://localhost/testsite/photo/example1.jpg&watermark=images/watermark.png" cannot be displayed because it contains errors

Comment: then save that resulting page and view the file like I said.

Comment: The error message look like an image file but it is not, I can see this. My problem is, why this script is not working properly? Everything looks good in explain of script page

Answer (score 0):

add the gd extentions in wampmanger - You should be able to add it from the php menu called something like php_gd

Comment: php_gd2 extention is checked in wamp

Comment: is there a space before the first <?php ?   There should be no space before or after the <?php tags

Comment: if you ask me there is a space in watermark.php, I'm using original file. So, I tried to delete all spaces but nothings change